# ios how to check a phone call is ended and based on that phone number i want to check in my app data base is it possible

Tags: ios, iphone

I have tried all the ways to retrieve ongoing call. I want to trace that a phone is ended or not and after ending the phone call i want to check that phone call in database. Please tell me

Comment: Show what you have tried and explain what is does wrong.

Comment: I have tried with carrier class of apple but that is not working

Comment: How - you need to be specific, show code and logging results